# pandas groupby and convert to json list

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like the following

```
idx, f1, f2, f3
1,   a,  a,  b
2,   b,  a,  c
3,   a,  b,  c
.
.
.
87   e,  e,  e
```

I need to convert the other columns to list of dictionaries based on idx column. so, final result should be:

```
idx, features
1 ,  [{f1:a, f2:a, f3:b}, {f1:b, f2:a, f3:c}, {f1:a, f2:b, f3:c}]
.
.
.
87,  [{f1: e, f2:e, f3:e}]
```

Is it possible to do something like this using groupby in pandas?

Comment: Where is your code to reproduce this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index` and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_json.html):

```
print df
    f1 f2 f3
idx         
1    a  a  b
1    b  a  c
1    a  b  c
87   e  e  e

print df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient='records'))

1     [{"f1":"a","f2":"a","f3":"b"},{"f1":"b","f2":"...
87                       [{"f1":"e","f2":"e","f3":"e"}]
dtype: object
```

Or if column `idx` is not `index`:

```
print df
   idx f1 f2 f3
0    1  a  a  b
1    1  b  a  c
2    1  a  b  c
3   87  e  e  e

print df.groupby('idx').apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient='records'))
idx
1     [{"idx":1,"f1":"a","f2":"a","f3":"b"},{"idx":1...
87              [{"idx":87,"f1":"e","f2":"e","f3":"e"}]
dtype: object
```

Comment: How does it works? Please dont forget accept solution, if was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: `to_json` creates a string-valued column, if you want to get a list of actual lists-of-dicts without re-parsing the json, you could do `df.groupby('idx').apply(lambda g: g.to_dict(orient='records'))`, and call `.tolist()` on the result to get just the list of lists-of-dicts, or `.to_dict()` to get a dictionary of `idx => [{f1: ..., f2: ..., f3: ...}]`

Comment: How can i give this json my pre-decided schema ? if i want only 2 of these columns out of 4 in json with some diff format ?

Comment: @j' - If understand correct, need custom function :(